# Tracking down unhandled exceptions in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly, tooling

Any idea on how to get the line number of an unhanded exception in blazor webassembly?

There was a discussion long ago on some work that still needs to be done by the team to have it working. I think that died down if I'm not mistaken.

Consider the message below. It leaves one completely in the dark with no guidance on where to start looking.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is SubstringValue() your code?

Comment: Nope I don't have that in. I know where the Null Reference exception is in this case. I'm looking for a way to have a line number in the output of where the exception occurred. If I'm not mistaken this plumbing has to be done by the mono guys?

Answer (score 0):

Not to be rude, but it is in the Blazor documentation to **always** handle exceptions yourself when interacting with components: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#global-exception-handling

Simply wrap your all your method bodies (even the lifecycle methods) with a `try/catch` block. Bonus points to inject the `ILogger<MyComponent>` for friendly logging.
Example:

```cs
@inject ILogger<MyComponent> Logger

<h1>@UserName</h1>

@code {
    private string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            NavigationManager.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
            var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            UserName = $"Hi, {authState.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "display_name")?.Value}!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"Failed to initialize MyComponent. Error: {ex}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No offense taken. Actually I welcome criticism. The reason I ask is because the Microsoft team actually spoke about addressing this seeing that every other programming model they've put forth supports this, except blazor.

Comment: Just as an added note. I do use try catches with pretty much all I write but you still can't extract a line number out of the Exception object.